# RubyMine searching with find usages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have just bought a license to use Ruby Mine and am really struggling to learn how to use it. I keep having to go back to Text Mate to do simple things like searching.

I'm trying to find where i have defined a css div (called "category title"). From what I can gather, I need to use 'Find Usages' in Ruby Mine. Most times when I go to the edit/find menu, 'find usages' is greyed out. Then, if I click on the uppermost 'app' folder, and click find usages, it searches for 'app'. It doesn't recognise the search in the search bar. If i type the div name in the code and click alt/F7, it gives me a typo warning rather than a search option.

Does anyone know how to search the entire app (not just the specific file of the app) in RubyMine? I'm finding this incredibly frustrating.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you need is `Find in Path` which will search your entire project, set of projects if they are open together, a specific director, etc. It has a bunch of options, including a regex search. For Mac, it is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, for windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Checkout this site for keyboard reference.

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/documentation/index.html

You might also try <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> which is search everywhere, files, classes, symbols.

Comment: To find a declaration, you can put the cursor on the name, then cmd-B (on Mac). It brings you to the declaration. I tested it and it seems to work with div as well.